# Poor bulk insert performance using Python 3 and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have few text files which contain URLs. I am trying to create a SQLite database to store these URLs in a table. The URL table has two columns i.e. primary key(INTEGER) and URL(TEXT).

I try to insert 100,000 entries in one insert command and loop till I finish the URL list. Basically, read all the text files content and save in list and then I use create smaller list of 100,000 entries and insert in table.

Total URLs in the text files are 4,591,415 and total text file size is approx 97.5 MB.

**Problems**:

1. When I chose file database, it takes around **7-7.5 minutes** to insert. I feel this is not a very fast insert given that I have solid state hard-disk which has faster read/write. Along with that I have approximately 10GB RAM available as seen in task manager. Processor is i5-6300U 2.4Ghz.
2. The total text files are approx. 97.5 MB. But after I insert the URLs in the SQLite, the SQLite database is approximately 350MB i.e. almost 3.5 times the original data size. Since the database doesn't contain any other tables, indexes etc. this database size looks little odd.

For problem 1, I tried playing with parameters and came up with as best ones based on test runs with different parameters.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr> 
<th>Configuration</th>
<th>Time</th>    
</tr>
  
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = delete and no transaction                           </th><th>0:12:09.888404</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = delete and with transaction                         </th><th>0:22:43.613580</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = memory and transaction                              </th><th>0:09:01.140017</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = memory                                              </th><th>0:07:38.820148</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = memory and synchronous=0                            </th><th>0:07:43.587135</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = memory and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535        </th><th>0:07:19.778217</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = memory and synchronous=0 and page_size=65535        </th><th>0:07:28.186541</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535        </th><th>0:07:06.539198</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=0 and page_size=65535        </th><th>0:07:19.810333</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = wal and synchronous=0 and page_size=65535           </th><th>0:08:22.856690</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = wal and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535           </th><th>0:08:22.326936</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=4096         </th><th>0:07:35.365883</th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = memory and synchronous=1 and page_size=4096         </th><th>0:07:15.183948</th></tr>
<tr><th>1,00,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535      </th><th>0:07:13.402985</th></tr>



</table>
```

I was checking online and saw this link https://adamyork.com/2017/07/02/fast-database-inserts-with-python-3-6-and-sqlite/ where the system is much slower than what I but still performing very well. 
Two things, that stood out from this link were:

1. The table in the link had more columns than what I have.
2. The database file didn't grow 3.5 times.

I have shared the python code and the files here: https://github.com/ksinghgithub/python_sqlite

Can someone guide me on optimizing this code. Thanks.

Environment:

1. Windows 10 Professional on i5-6300U and 20GB RAM and 512 SSD.
2. Python 3.7.0

***Edit 1:: New performance chart based on the feedback received on UNIQUE constraint and me playing with cache size value.***

```
self.db.execute('CREATE TABLE blacklist (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, url TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)')
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr> 
<th>Configuration</th>
<th>Action</th>
<th>Time</th>    
<th>Notes</th>
</tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = 8192</th><th>REMOVE UNIQUE FROM URL</th><th>0:00:18.011823</th><th>Size reduced to 196MB from 350MB</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>50,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = default</th><th>REMOVE UNIQUE FROM URL</th><th>0:00:25.692283</th><th>Size reduced to 196MB from 350MB</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>100,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 </th><th></th><th>0:07:13.402985</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>100,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = 4096</th><th></th><th>0:04:47.624909</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>100,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = 8192</th><th></th><<th>0:03:32.473927</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>100,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = 8192</th><th>REMOVE UNIQUE FROM URL</th><th>0:00:17.927050</th><th>Size reduced to 196MB from 350MB</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>100,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = default   </th><th>REMOVE UNIQUE FROM URL</th><th>0:00:21.804679</th><th>Size reduced to 196MB from 350MB</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>100,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = default   </th><th>REMOVE UNIQUE FROM URL & ID</th><th>0:00:14.062386</th><th>Size reduced to 134MB from 350MB</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th>100,000 - with journal = delete and synchronous=1 and page_size=65535 cache_size = default   </th><th>REMOVE UNIQUE FROM URL & DELETE ID</th><th>0:00:11.961004</th><th>Size reduced to 134MB from 350MB</th><th></th></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite uses auto-commit mode by default. This permits `begin transaction` be to omitted. But here we want all the inserts to be in a transaction and the only way to do that is to start a transaction with `begin transaction` so that all the statements that are going to be ran are all in that transaction.

The method `executemany` is only a loop over `execute` done outside Python that calls the SQLite prepare statement function only once.

The following is a really bad way to remove the last N items from a list:

```
    templist = []
    i = 0
    while i < self.bulk_insert_entries and len(urls) > 0:
        templist.append(urls.pop())
        i += 1
```

It is better to do this:

```
   templist = urls[-self.bulk_insert_entries:]
   del urls[-self.bulk_insert_entries:]
   i = len(templist)
```

The slice and del slice work even on an empty list.

Both might have the same complexity but 100K calls to append and pop costs a lot more than letting Python do it outside the interpreter.

Comment: Sadly, not much gains by using new list mechanism and adding transaction. 
1. No transaction original list mechanism = 0:05:13.974366
2. No transaction slice/del mechanism = 0:05:05.689453
3. Wrap insert statement only in transaction and slice/del list mechanism = 0:07:27.693308
4. Transaction outside while loop and slice/del list mechanism = 0:05:07.213928

Answer (score 0):

The UNIQUE constraint on column "url" is creating an implicit index on the URL. That would explain the size increase.

I don't think you can populate the table and afterwards add the unique constraint.

Your bottleneck is surely the CPU. Try the following:

1. Install toolz: `pip install toolz`
2. Use this method:

   ```
   from toolz import partition_all

   def add_blacklist_url(self, urls):
       # print('add_blacklist_url:: entries = {}'.format(len(urls)))
       start_time = datetime.now()
       for batch in partition_all(100000, urls):
           try:
               start_commit = datetime.now()
               self.cursor.executemany('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO blacklist(url) VALUES(:url)''', batch)
               end_commit = datetime.now() - start_commit
               print('add_blacklist_url:: total time for INSERT OR IGNORE INTO blacklist {} entries = {}'.format(len(templist), end_commit))
           except sqlite3.Error as e:
               print("add_blacklist_url:: Database error: %s" % e)
           except Exception as e:
               print("add_blacklist_url:: Exception in _query: %s" % e)
       self.db.commit()
       time_elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time
       print('add_blacklist_url:: total time for {} entries = {}'.format(records, time_elapsed))
   ```

The code was not tested.

Comment: Is there an option to trim the index once done? Secondly, I think the bottleneck probably is the database itself because I have tried closing all the applications and just running the script and in Task Manager I see write speed of around 3-4 MB/s. But when I am just reading the text files it shows around 30-35 MB/s

Comment: A bootleneck has to be a resource of your computer. It could be the disk or the CPU. If you don't see the CPU using one core at 100%, it's the disk.

Comment: What do you mean by trimming the index? Like a sort of compaction? I don't think it's possible but you can try a full VACUUM.

Comment: when i run the script, neither is running 100% in task manager. CPU is close to 50% and disk between 5-7%.

Comment: i5-6300U has 2 cores so 50% CPU means that one core is at 100%. Your Python code is too slow. I'll post some tips.

Comment: I'd recommend trying with smaller batches. 100K seems excessive.

Comment: The code above didnt help to be honest. After removing the UNIQUE constraint on primary key, using the the above code i achieved  0:06:32.189346. Also, it seems this partition makes a copy of URL list as opposed to mine where I pop from one and push on another because this new code clocked almost 1500MB in RAM consumption. Also, this code somehow increased too many writes on journal file and i could see journal file go even 100MBs. This was not seen in my previous code.

Comment: Partition does create a new list but it's short (100K) and short-lived. Popping and appending 1 item at a time is slow. If you don't want to use partition, use slices to copy entire chunks at a time.

Comment: A significant difference between our codes is that mine commits after every batch and yours only when done. I don't know how it will perform with only 1 transaction for all, give it a shot!

Comment: with all optimizations and single commit = 0:02:13.202081
with all optimizations and commit every batch of 100k = 0:04:03.772711

Comment: That's enlightening. Thank you for sharing! Updated post.